# Some android phones getting Window has no method openDatabase

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova

I am getting Window has no method openDatabase in some android phones like HTC version 4.3.

I developed application but facing above issue not in all devices in some devices only.

```
function CALL_DB() {
try {
        console.log("call_db");
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("call_db Error processing SQL: " + err);
    }
}
```

`CALL_DB` function i called on deviceready event.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Probably because you only wrote: "i developed an app and got an error". How about the basics, like the LogCat logs?

Comment: @IdanAdar Already maintained error "Window has no method openDatabase"... for that No any error I am getting.